# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'laptop_lid' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, one-to-one

i started learning hibernate framework,but i had some problems when i started learning relational mapping : One To One

that's my **Hibernate.cfg.xml
**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
      
      <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aliens </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
            <property name = "hbm2ddl">update</property>
        <property name = "show_sql">true</property>
      <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
      
      <mapping  class= "com.jee.projetHibernate.Student"/>
             <mapping  class= "com.jee.projetHibernate.Laptop"/>
      
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

that's my Student class

```
package com.jee.projetHibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userid")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="username")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne
private Laptop laptop;
    
    public Laptop getLaptop() {
        return laptop;
    }
    public void setLaptop(Laptop laptop) {
        this.laptop = laptop;
    }
    public Student() {
        super();
    }
    public Student(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    
    
    
}
```

that's my Laptop class

```
package com.jee.projetHibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "laptop")
public class Laptop {
    
    
    @Id
    private int lid;
    private String lname;
    public int getLid() {
        return lid;
    }
    public void setLid(int lid) {
        this.lid = lid;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    
    
    

}
```

and taht's my app.java

```
package com.jee.projetHibernate;
 
import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.*;
import com.mysql.cj.Session;
import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    
        
        Laptop lap2=new Laptop();
        lap2.setLid(3);
        lap2.setLname("macbook");
        
        
         Student alien=new Student(); 
         alien.setName("marah"); 
         alien.setLaptop(lap2);
        
         
        
        
Configuration conf =new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).addAnnotatedClass(Laptop.class);
StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry= new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sf=conf.buildSessionFactory();
org.hibernate.Session session=sf.openSession();

Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
//to save data in database

session.save(lap2);
session.save(alien);

tx.commit();
        
//to fetch or get data from database
/*
 * alien2=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 17); System.out.println(alien2);
 */
      
        
    
        
  
        
        //save method belongs to session interface that belongs to hibernate
        /*
         * Configuration conf=new
         * Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Aliens.class);
         * org.hibernate.SessionFactory sf=conf.buildSessionFactory();
         * org.hibernate.Session session= sf.openSession(); Transaction
         * tx=session.beginTransaction(); session.save(alien); tx.commit();
         */
        
        
        
        
        
    }
}
```

i expected that 2 tables are going to get values that i inserted in my java code , but  all i'm getting is an error

```
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: insert into laptop (lname, lid) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (laptop_lid, username) values (?, ?)
oct. 28, 2022 3:30:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
oct. 28, 2022 3:30:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'laptop_lid' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:660)
    at com.jee.projetHibernate.App.main(App.java:44)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'laptop_lid' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: What does the error say? Unknown column, it means the column you have in the code is not in the table. Student model doesn't have `laptop_lid` attribute nor column

Comment: yeah ,but it has to be created as a foreign key ,because i used one To One mapping

Comment: I understand. But it's not defined in your model, therefore, it's not being created

Comment: i don't know why hibernate fails to create my tables , i think that's the problem i'll try to put the error i get

Comment: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table answer (answer_id integer not null, answer varchar(255), primary key (answer_id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1